# IPv6 tunnel broker, other devices unable to access ipv6 internet

Tags: ipv6, tunnel

I'm trying to use a Raspberry Pi to set up as a tunnel broker via tunnelbroker.net.

I have a simple set up that looks roughly like this:

```
Verizon ISP Switch/IPv4 Router
        |
        |----- Raspberry Pi - set as DMZ Host
        |----- DevLaptop
```

The tunnel is set up properly via the Raspberry Pi since I'm able to `ping6 ipv6.google.com`
I'm also able to ping the IPv6 gateway from the Raspberry Pi

I'm trying to get `DevLaptop` to access IPv6 networks as well via `radvd` on the Raspberry PI.

Even though `DevLaptop` is able to obtain an IPv6 address I'm not able to `ping6 ipv6.google.com`. I get the error message `unknown host`

First, here's the config on the Raspberry device.

## ip -6 route show

```
::/96 dev sit0  proto kernel  metric 256 
2001:470:1f0e:6b7::1 dev he-ipv6  metric 1024 
2001:470:1f0e:6b7::/64 dev he-ipv6  proto kernel  metric 256 
2001:470:1f0f:6b7::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev he-ipv6  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
default via 2001:470:1f0e:6b7::1 dev he-ipv6  metric 1024
```

## RPi config

```
#/etc/network/interfaces
iface default inet dhcp

iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.3
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.255.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1

auto he-ipv6
iface he-ipv6 inet6 v4tunnel
        address 2001:470:1f0e:6b7::2
        netmask 64
        endpoint 184.105.253.10
        local 192.168.1.3
        ttl 255
        gateway 2001:470:1f0e:6b7::1

        #notice :1f0f: and not :1f0e:
        up ip addr add 2001:470:1f0f:6b7::1/64 dev eth0 

#/etc/sysctl.conf
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1

#/etc/radvd.conf
interface eth0
{
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    prefix 2001:470:1f0f:6b7::/64
    {
        AdvOnLink on;
        AdvAutonomous on;
    };
};
```

---

Here's `DevLaptop`'s obtained ipv6 address.

## ifconfig

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d8:eb:97:b3:05:c9  
          inet6 addr: 2001:470:1f0f:6b7:daeb:97ff:feb3:5c9/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::daeb:97ff:feb3:5c9/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2001:470:1f0f:6b7:1ceb:5449:6d4:efb6/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:155 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:151 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:24409 (24.4 KB)  TX bytes:32980 (32.9 KB)
```

## $ ip -6 route show

```
2001:470:1f0f:6b7::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256  expires 86348sec
fe80::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256 
default via fe80::ba27:ebff:fed5:b552 dev eth1  proto static  metric 1 
default via fe80::ba27:ebff:fed5:b552 dev eth1  proto ra  metric 1024  expires 1748sec
```

The only thing I'm able to do from `DevLaptop` is ping and get a response from the Raspberry with `ping6 2001:470:1f0f:6b7::1`

I wanted to do this as a weekend project to start getting familiar with IPv6 networks. Can someone point me in the right direction as to why `DevLaptop` is unable to reach other IPv6 networks? I was under the impression IPv6 devices would auto configure themselves after receiving a router advertisement. Is there something I'm missing?

*Bonus question*: My ipv6 tunnel broker is also offering a different /48 address besides the /64 address I listed above. What is the purpose of using a /48 network address versus /64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put the same subnet on both the tunnel and your local LAN. Tunnelbroker.net will have given you a separate /64 for your LAN and you can even request a whole /48 if you have multiple LANs. Use those and it should work.

Comment: You were right, thanks. The broker endpoint was `2001:470:1f0e` while subnet for my LAN was `2001:470:1f0f`. I had simply used the wrong one like you said. However, is there a way to refresh the interface? When I changed the routing advertisement the laptop had the IP from the correct subnet immediately but I wasn't able to connect to the internet after like 5 minutes.

Comment: Yes, radvd doesn't work without it.

Comment: Please edit your question and put in the right addresses. Can you also show your IPv6 routing table? And if you've configured it your ip6tables.

Comment: I've updated my config above. I have not configured any ip6tables yet.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the routing table of your RPi ☺

Comment: I just found out I'm able to `ping6 2607:f8b0:4000:807::1008` (Google IP) but not `ping6 ipv6.google.com` I still get the error `unknown host`. Seems DNS related... not sure where to start though.

Comment: Updated question with RPi routing table you requested too.

Comment: Try asking a public DNS resolver directly: `dig @8.8.8.8 www.google.com aaaa`. Asking over IPv6 shouldn't make a difference: `dig @2001:4860:4860::8888 www.google.com aaaa`.

Comment: Routing looks good!

Comment: `dig @8.8.8.8 www.google.com aaaa` gives the output: `; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-4.3ubuntu0.2-Ubuntu <<>> @8.8.8.8 www.google.com aaaa
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
`

Comment: While `dig @2001:4860:4860::8888 www.google.com aaaa` Gives an answer as expected

Comment: That looks like your IPv4 routing is failing

Comment: So your IPv4 is broken and your IPv6 is working ☺ If you put the Google IPv6 resolvers `2001:4860:4860::8888` and `2001:4860:4860::8844` in your resolv.conf then you'll at least have working DNS again.

Comment: In the `RPi` or `DevLaptop`? I hope I don't have to manually input that DNS for every future host on my network :(

Comment: On the DevLaptop (for now). As long as your IPv4 on that laptop is broken you'll need IPv6 DNS resolvers to have some connectivity. Usually you'd provision IPv6 DNS resolvers either through the RDNSS option in the RA or by using stateless DHCPv6.